# Split Cell using SSIS

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm looking to use SSIS to transform the data held from a single source table. One of the cells has a string of characters. For example:

```
##/\/\/\/\/\##HHHHHHBBBB##/\/\/\/\/\
```

There's also another cell on the same row which contains a date.

Basically I want a each character within that string to be transferred to a new table as a row on it's own. The first two characters represent the date given in the other cell. The next two characters represent the following day and so on. So as well as having each character on it's own I would also want to increment the data and store that too.

Any idea how I would go about doing this or even if SSIS is the correct tool to be using.

Many Thanks

Comment: The question is quite confusing, You should edit your question and add real-world example: input row and all output rows. However, use Derived Column and Pivot/Unpivot in SSIS. Test performance and decide whether You will use SSIS or SQL as LeedsDBA suggested.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you'd be better running this through a split-string function in SQL first? That way you'l be getting rows for each character along-side the date, and then you can just output it straight to a destination.

I've created a function to facilitate this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_SplitStringIntoRows](@text varchar(max))
    RETURNS @tbl TABLE ([value] char(1) NOT NULL)
AS
BEGIN

    WHILE len(@text) > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tbl
        SELECT left(@text,1)

        SET @text = RIGHT(@text,len(@text)-1)

    END

    RETURN
END
```

Then, to test the data i created a quick temp table with your data in:

```
DECLARE @source as TABLE([value] varchar(max), [date] datetime)

INSERT INTO @source
SELECT '##/\/\/\/\/\##HHHHHHBBBB##/\/\/\/\/\', getdate()
UNION
SELECT '##/\/\/\/\/\##HHHHHHBBBB##/\/\/\/\/\', getdate()+1
UNION
SELECT '##/\/\/\/\/\##HHHHHHBBBB##/\/\/\/\/\', getdate()+2
```

Then cross applied the function to this dataset:

```
SELECT d.[value], s.date
FROM @source s
CROSS APPLY dbo.[udf_SplitStringIntoRows](s.value) d
```

Which should give you the source dataset you require to further process in SSIS.